C# Razor pages : date time formatting is not taken into consideration in UI
I have the following model class:
public sealed class Vignette
{
    [Required]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Required]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}")]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}")]
    public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }

    public Notification? Notification { get; set; }
}

This is my page UI:
<div class="form-floating mb-3 mt-3">
    <input asp-for="@Model.Vignette.StartDate" class="form-control" />
    <label for="Vignette_StartDate">...</label>
    <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Vignette.StartDate" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>

And the code behind:
public void OnGet()
{
   Vignette = new Vignette()
   {
       StartDate = DateTime.Now
   };
}

But is displayed as (on all browsers: firefox, chrome, brave, edge):

There is different format than I enforced in my model. I expected to have already pre-populated with default value (set on server-side OnGet method)
I also tried with:
<input asp-for="@Model.Vignette.StartDate" class="form-control" asp-format="{0:dd-MM-yyyy}"/>

but I get the same thing.
Why ?

I would start by running the date into a variable with tostring right after the OnGet to see if it is getting the format properly.  I believe that the browser overrides date formats so even though its formatted one way in the C# side it won't matter. See the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format

The format for a browser date control is always yyyy-MM-dd:
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]

Let the control take care of formatting based on the user's culture.
See https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/forms/dates-and-times
Get rid of the @Model in the asp-for attribute too:
<input asp-for="Vignette.StartDate" class="form-control" />

